# How can i read csv from zip file python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to read csv which is in zip file. My task is to read the file rad_15min.csv file but the issue is when i read zip file (I copied link address by clicking on download button) it gives me error:

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/lucafrance/bike-traffic-in-munich/download?datasetVersionNumber=7')
```

**Error:**
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 9, saw 2

Data: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/lucafrance/bike-traffic-in-munich

Zip file Link: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/lucafrance/bike-traffic-in-munich/download?datasetVersionNumber=7

I have to read this csv dynamically, I dont want to download it, All just to make a download link and then read csv dynamically. Is there any other approach which i can try ?

Comment: Check line 9 of the file, the error says it finds 2 fileds, instead of one (I m not able to download the file because I am not registered with Kaggle). i.e. the problem is with the file format, not that it is zipped. Maybe the file use different separator/decimal point etc. than what you expect

Comment: Thanks @buran for your message. I am just reading csv only 2 lines of code. If you are not able to download the file, I have sent the link above named as data. May be you can try please and let me know. I have been trying it but all in vain .

Comment: You have to login before reach the file, you need authentication for your request.

Comment: Also note, the docs for `compression`: If using ‘zip’ or ‘tar’, the ZIP file must contain only one data file to be read in. And it look like your zip file has 3, according to the data description: _Content The data is split in three files_

Comment: @buran, Can you please give me the code, so i can testify !

Comment: You need to use the [API](https://www.kaggle.com/docs/api). And as a side note, how do you want to read a zip of 3 csv with pandas ?

Comment: Okay, I want to read only 1 file in a zip named as rad15_min.csv, with pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I tried using kaggle API.. but i dont want to download the data, just read dynamically*.
> *I want to read only 1 file in a `zip` named as `rad15_min.csv`, with pandas*

You can try making a [request](https://fr.python-requests.org/en/latest/) with the [__Host-KAGGLEID](https://www.kaggle.com/cookies) cookie.

I'm not sure if there is a programatic way to get this one but you can always hardcode it. On your keyboard, press (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) to open the Developer Tools of your browser and go to `Applications`/`Cookies` and copy the concerned cookie (and make sure you're logged-in before in [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/)).

```
import requests

url = "https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/" \
      "lucafrance/bike-traffic-in-munich/" \
      "download?datasetVersionNumber=7"

cookies = {"__Host-KAGGLEID": "CfDJ8IPkmlRqhQhDn1PidxljKKQWcrozwJuFfsIn..."}

response = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)

from zipfile import ZipFile
from io import BytesIO

with ZipFile(BytesIO(response.content)) as zf:
    df = pd.read_csv(zf.open("rad_15min.csv")) # not rad15_min.csv
```

NB : If the `zip` has only one csv OR if the dataset is not an archive (*i.e, a single csv*), you can pass `BytesIO(response.content)` directly to [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Output :

```
print(df)

              datum uhrzeit_start  ... richtung_2 gesamt
0        2017.01.01         00:00  ...          0      0
1        2017.01.01         00:00  ...          0      0
2        2017.01.01         00:00  ...          0      0
3        2017.01.01         00:00  ...          0      0
4        2017.01.01         00:00  ...          0      0
...             ...           ...  ...        ...    ...
1255761  2022.12.31         23:45  ...          2      7
1255762  2022.12.31         23:45  ...          0      0
1255763  2022.12.31         23:45  ...          0      0
1255764  2022.12.31         23:45  ...          0      0
1255765  2022.12.31         23:45  ...          5     17

[1255766 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. But if someone test this code, it will throw the error because of Hostid. Cannot we make it dynamic ?

Comment: You skimmed over my answer! I said that I'm unsure whether we can get this particular cookie dynamically. Also, if someone may need to test this code in the future, they'll need to follow the instructions I provided ;).

Answer (score -1):

For me, it's forwarding to the HTML page, instead of downloading.
Why not use the kaggle API that is provided? (You need first to provide a token)

this is what i tried:

```
import csv
import requests

url = 'https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/lucafrance/bike-traffic-in-munich/download?datasetVersionNumber=7'

# Open the URL and create a response object
response = requests.get(url)

# Create a CSV reader object
csv_reader = csv.reader(response.iter_lines(decode_unicode=True), delimiter=',')

# Iterate over each row in the CSV file
for row in csv_reader:
    # Process each row as needed
    print(row)
```

What i got back is this:

```
[]
[]
['<!DOCTYPE html>']
['<html lang="en">']
[]
['<head>']
['  <title>Bike Traffic in Munich | Kaggle</title>']
['  <meta charset="utf-8" />']
['    <meta name="robots" content="index', ' follow" />']
['  <meta name="description" content="Bike traffic measured over time at different stations in Munich." />']
['  <meta name="turbolinks-cache-control" content="no-cache" />']
```

Comment: I tried using kaggle API, it is downloading but i dont want to download the data, just read dynamically, Can you check it ?